# Delete a key (and value) from ember object

Tags: ember.js

Ember newbie and I have a feeling I am doing something very wrong here.  Basically, I am trying to use an action to delete a key from a custom ember object.  The action takes the key as the parameter (though that's a very jquery way to do it - perhaps I am missing a more "ember" way to do it?)

I created a [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/16494220538ef0947b2ddac1a2861877?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C)

I am able to set the value to null which kind of works, but I'd prefer to remove the key and the value entirely.  I would think .removeObject(key) would be the ticket, but it doesn't work.  The console complains with:

```
Uncaught TypeError: thisData.removeObject is not a function
```

So I think I am using it in the wrong context.

Here's my example controller:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

const UrlObj = Ember.Object.extend({});

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    urlData: UrlObj.create({
        queryParams: {
            filter_breadcrumb: [
                'Jewelry > Rings',
                'Clothing and Accessories > Sweaters'
            ],
            filter_price: ['100.0-200.0'],
            filter_size: ['S','L'],
            paging: 18,
            q: 'gold',
            search_sort: 'relevance'
        }
    }),
    actions: {
        deleteStuff(key) {
            alert("deleteStuff called with " + key);
            let thisData = Ember.get(this.urlData, 'queryParams');

            //thisData.removeObject(key); // doesn't work, wrong context?
            //Ember.get(this.urlData, 'queryParams').removeObject(key); // doesn't work, wrong context?
            //delete thisData[key]; // this deletes it from the object but it's JS so ember is not aware of it

            Ember.set(thisData, key, null); // this kind of works, but I'd like to remove the key AND the value
        }
    }
});
```

I commented out the lines that don't work.

Here's my template:

```
here's the data list:<br>
{{#each-in urlData.queryParams as |key value|}}
<a href="#" {{action "deleteStuff" key}}>{{key}}: {{value}}</a><br>
{{/each-in}}
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to notify property changed.

And no need to use `Ember.Object`

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    urlData: {
        queryParams: {
            filter_breadcrumb: [
                 'Jewelry > Rings',
                 'Clothing and Accessories > Sweaters'
            ],
            filter_price: ['100.0-200.0'],
            filter_size: ['S','L'],
            paging: 18,
            q: 'gold',
            search_sort: 'relevance'
        }
    },
  actions: {
        deleteStuff(key) {
      alert("deleteStuff called with " + key);
      let thisData = Ember.get(this.urlData, 'queryParams');     
      delete thisData[key]; 
      this.notifyPropertyChange('urlData');


    }
  }

});
```

Comment: Can you think of a reason why this same basic setup wouldn't work at the route level?  I moved it there and the action fires without any errors, but the deleted key and value still appear in the view.  The key is being deleted by from the ember object though - I can tell when I output it to the console.  You can see my code here https://ember-twiddle.com/16494220538ef0947b2ddac1a2861877?openFiles=routes.search.js%2C but for some reason twiddle isn't rendering my template (it works when I run it locally)

Comment: @midget2000x Because the property rendered in the templates owned by controller not route. I mean those properties in controllers could be rendered in templates. And you set the `urlData` in `setupController` for the controller. When a template would be rendered, the props to be rendered should be in controller. So if you want your new setup work, you need to change the line property change by this : ` this.controllerFor('search').notifyPropertyChange('urlData');`

Answer (score 0):

No need to use "notifyPropertyChange"

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({

urlData: {
    queryParams: { 

        filter_breadcrumb: [
             'Jewelry > Rings',
             'Clothing and Accessories > Sweaters'
        ],
        filter_price: ['100.0-200.0'],
        filter_size: ['S','L'],
        paging: 18,`enter code here`
        q: 'gold',
        search_sort: 'relevance'
    }
},
actions: {

  deleteStuff(key) {
  alert("deleteStuff called with " + key);
  let thisData = this.get('urlData').queryParams;     
  delete thisData[key]; 
  console.log(this.get('urlData')); //u ll get deleted data


}
}

});
```